# How I can run my App on my iOS device in Xcode 9 ?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have a problems when I want to run my application on my iPhone in Xcode 9 and using Swift lang.
When  I run this application in simulator everything is all right, but when I connect my iPhone (by cable or wireless) to my MBP I have an error:

> Swift stdlib tool Error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0

and application stopped.

Why I have this error message and how can I test my app on my devices?

Thanks for all answers.

P.S.: Xcode 9.2 (9C40b) iOS 11.2 (Deployment target)

Comment: iPhone 6
11.2.5

Comment: try to remove `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Comment: I removed ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/, but problem persists.
Maybe this somehow depends on developer account?

Comment: you need to remove the Derived Data _while_ Xocde is closed.

Comment: I read log info about this problem. I think i have this problem because i don’t have paid Apple Developer sertificate.

Answer (score 0):

If removing DerivedData don't help try to just reboot phone or mac.
It mainly works for me with that error